# Get R.drawable int inside of onClick()

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have a few ImageViews, all using the same onClick(). How can I get the ID or R.drawable int from the specific ImageView to open another Image depending on the Image I clicked on?

Comment: Do you actually want to identify which `ImageView` was clicked or do you really need to know which `Drawable` the `ImageView` contains? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you have some image views in your xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_drawable_1"
        android:onClick="doSomething" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_drawable_2"
        android:onClick="doSomething" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_drawable_3"
        android:onClick="doSomething" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You have to add this method to your Activity:

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.image_1:
            // You clicked on image 1
            // If you need to do something to the ImageView with this particular Id then uncomment the next line.
            // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
            break;
        case R.id.image_2:
            // You clicked on image 2
            break;
        case R.id.image_3:
            // You clicked on image 3
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getResources().getDrawable`

Example:

```
ImageView myImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImg); 
myImg.setImageResource = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the resource identifier that was used to generate the Drawable for the ImageView, but you can save it as a tag of the ImageView when you set the image programmatically.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_resource);
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.image_resource);
```

You can than later retrieve it like that:

```
int imageResource = (Integer) imageView.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

I stored the Ids of the images which are shown by clicking the onClick() in an int-array, so I created something like a workaround to deal with that issue.

My onClick() looks like this now:

```
public void showPictureZoomDialog(View view)
{
    int singlePicValue400 = 0;

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic1:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[0];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic2:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[1];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic3:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[2];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic4:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[3];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic5:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[4];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic6:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[5];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic7:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[6];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic8:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[7];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic9:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[8];
                break;
            case R.id.picture_imgvw_pic10:
                singlePicValue400 = currentPicSite.getPicValues400()[9];
                break;
        }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureZoomDialog.class);
    intent.putExtra("PICID", singlePicValue400);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I get the Id of the image I want to display via the Intent:

```
public class PictureZoomDialog extends Activity {

private ImageView mDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_zoom_dialog);

    mDialog = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pictureactivity_imgvw_pic1);
    mDialog.setClickable(true);
    mDialog.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("PICID",-1));

    mDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thx a lot guys for getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to get the current Drawable from the ImageView.

```
Drawable myDrawable = YourImageView.getDrawable();
```

Then you can go ahead and use `myDrawable` where ever you want.